# How do I stop trains from switching tracks in a 'stupid' way

Tags: openttd

Consider this situation, all signals are Path-signals: [image: one train blocking the other]
Obviously, it would have been more efficient if the first departing train would have reserved the bottom track. What happened is that the first train actually broke down, blocking the other.

Also, the reverse happens. Both trains are coming from the right side of the picture, each reserving their own track, and it only messes up at the last signal, where the train on the upper track reserves the lower platform, thus completely stopping the other train.

Is there any way of making sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: Do you have two parallel tracks running all the way to the destination? If so, why allow the trains to change tracks at all?

Comment: @YellowMegaMan, I'm assuming there are more that two trains on this track. Or at least he's planning for the future.

Comment: @svick yes, there are three trains running on these two tracks. I also built two tracks to make sure trains could pass a broken down train.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to use one-way signals on each of those tracks. That way, you'll be forcing the travel direction on each track.

In your screenshot, I'd force left-to-right direction for the bottom track, and right-to-left to the top one. If you are British, probably you'll want it reversed.

Read about [path signals](http://wiki.openttd.org/Signals#Path_signals) on the OpenTTD wiki. There are two types of path signals: a standard, and a one-way. You'll want to use the one-way path signal.

Also read about [terminal stations](http://wiki.openttd.org/Railway_station#Terminus) for suggestions on how to place signals near the station itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since your running 2 tracks for 2 trains, just seperate them instead of making it complicated? Otherwise use 1 way path signals.